# Difference between using a mutex locker and locking the mutex manually

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

Specifically, in a const member function if I use `mutex.lock()` at the beginning of it, and `mutex.unlock()` right before the return, I get crashes when running it inside an OpenMP loop. But if I replace those two calls with one `QMutexLocker(&mutex)` at the beginning of the function, it runs smoothly.
Visual Studio 2010, Qt 4.8.
I would expect the two codes to be equivalent, but they are obviously not. What am I missing here?

EDIT:
Although this doesn't reproduce the problem, a small example:

```
class TileCache
{
public:
    bool fillBuffer(const std::string& name) const {
        //QMutexLocker lock(&mCacheMutex);
        mCacheMutex.lock();
        auto ite = mCache.find(name);
        if(ite == mCache.end())
            mCache.insert(ite, std::make_pair(name, new unsigned char[1024]));
        // code here
        mCacheMutex.unlock();
        return true;
    }
private:
    mutable std::map<std::string, unsigned char*> mCache;
    mutable QMutex mCacheMutex;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Test" << std::endl;
    TileCache cache;
#pragma omp parallel for shared(cache)
    for(int i = 0; i < 2048; ++i)
    {
        cache.fillBuffer("my buffer");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I was basically asking if there is any known reason to believe that the two ways are not equivalent, if always calling `lock()`/`unlock()` (no `lock()` call without its matching `unlock()`) can behave differently than `QMutexLocker`, under some circumstances.

Comment: A real small code snippet showing the problem

Comment: I've run the application again, this time with run time checks enabled. It's showing stack corruption around a variable declared in the scope of the function.

Comment: The manual lock/unlock is not exception safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The advantage of a locker object is that automatically handles all exit points, including ones caused by exceptions.

Normally forgetting an exit point or an exception however just leaves the mutex locked and the symptom is the program just hanging.

If you are having a crash then the problem is somewhere else and the fact that you see the problem disappearing when using a locker object is just a coincidence (if there is a crash the program is for sure buggy, if there is no crash you cannot say the program is correct... especially in a language like C++ at has the concept of "undefined behavior").

### Edit

Another non-obvious advantage is that using a locker object created as first statement you're guaranteed that unlocking will happen as last thing before returning to the caller. This can make a difference if there are other objects created inside the function that depend on the mutex:

```
void ok_func() {
    Locker mylock(mymutex);
    Obj myobj; // constructor and destructor require the lock
}

void buggy_func() {
    lock(mymutex);
    Obj myobj; // constructor and destructor require the lock
    unlock(mymutex);
    // Bug: myobj instance will be destroyed without the lock
}


void workaround_func() {
    lock(mymutex);
    {   // nested scope needed
        Obj myobj; // constructor and destructor require the lock
    }
    unlock(mymutex);
}
```

Comment: After all, it was a problem of some objects with non trivial destructors that were created inside the scope of the function. The unlock() call released the mutex before these destructors completed, causing race conditions.
Many thanks for the comment, it got me investigating the inner code of the method to finally find the problem.

Comment: @LeCoc: nice to hear that you found the problem. Indeed this is another non obvious advantage of using locker objects. As destruction happens in reverse order of construction if you create the locker on enter you're also guaranteed that unlocking will happen right before leaving the function (i.e. also after the execution of all other local instances destructor). Edited the answer to show this more clearly...

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmutexlocker.html) it seems that the QMutexLocker somewhat managed meaning that it will auto-magically unlock whenever you go out of scope. If your const member function will only have one possible return path, then either method is fine. However, if this function becomes more complex or if you change the design at a later point, I would just use the class.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, found the problem after following the advice from @6502. First a small example that reproduces the problem:

```
class TileCache
{
    struct Culprit
    {
        Culprit(int& n) : mN(n) { ++mN; }
        ~Culprit() { --mN; }
    private:
        int& mN;
    };
public:
    int& fillBuffer(const std::string& name) const {
        //QMutexLocker lock(&mCacheMutex);
        mCacheMutex.lock();
        auto ite = mCache.find(name);
        if(ite == mCache.end())
            ite = mCache.insert(ite, std::make_pair(name, 0));
        Culprit culprit(ite->second);
        unsigned char somebuffer[1];
        somebuffer[ (ite->second -1) * 8192 ] = 'Q';
        mCacheMutex.unlock();
        return ite->second;
    }
private:
    mutable std::map<std::string, int> mCache;
    mutable QMutex mCacheMutex;
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    TileCache cache;
#pragma omp parallel for shared(cache) num_threads(2)
    for(int i = 0; i < 2048; ++i)
    {
        int& n = cache.fillBuffer("my buffer");
        if(n != 0) throw std::logic_error("Buff");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The sole difference between using QMutexLocker and manually lock/unlock was that in the locker case the unlock method will be called when exiting scope, in the reverse order of creation for that scope. That is what I didn't see, some objects inside the fillBuffer method do also RIIA, so the end of the fillBuffer method should not be the end of the protected section.
By using the mutex locker, the unlock() method is called last, protecting the whole method. It also works, of course, to have braces to delimit an inner scope where all the fillBuffer method will be doing its work:

```
int& fillBuffer(....) const {
    mCacheMutex.lock();
    {
        auto ite = ....
        ...
    }
    mCacheMutex.unlock();
}
```

But the real function has some other return points, which prevent this solution from working.

TL;DR
So I learnt that yes, it's not equivalent to have a scope based mutex locker compared with manual calls to lock() and unlock(), if the destructors of the objects created inside that scope should also be protected. *In this case, the scoped lock will work, but the manual calls will not*.

Many thanks to all that tried to help me, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

As the [description](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutexlocker.html#details) says if you have a function with many exit point, you need to write `mutex.unlock()` to every exit point. But if you use a mutex locker you don't have to do this.

Comment: The function has all its "return" statements preceded by unlock. I am now puzzled with the problem of the stack corruption, and the fact that it doesn't happen with QMutexLocker. It's late here, I'll further investigate tomorrow and write the results here.

Comment: It looks like when you investigate the code for QMutexLocker (i am looking at qt 4.2.2) right now, i think it does not always lock or unlock. I cannot really decipher the logic behind when it is locking or not, but maybe you also havr a copy of your mutex in another thread which never gets reset because its another instance. What happens if you allocate your mutex on the heap?